# Migration Issue Blogger To WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, migration

I have recently moved my 1 year old Blog with 2.5k posts to WordPress. After moving my blog to WordPress something goes wrong for me. Some of my blog posts paragraph has ruined and all of paragraph has no space each other. How i can solve this text formatting issue.

Check the problem Here :- [Blog Post](https://99lyricstore.com/2019/07/baby-baby-lyrics-mankirt.html)

Answer (score 0):

As word press editor picks empty spacing as extra spacing in different paragraph . Try to remove that . there are so many empty `<p>` tags generated because of empty space.